# issues getting json content

Tags: php, json, api, curl, file-get-contents

Hi i'm trying to get the content from a json file, but i can't i have many troubles to do it, my code is:

```
<?PHP

$url = 'http://www.taringa.net/api/efc6d445985d5c38c5515dfba8b74e74/json/Users-GetUserData/apptastico';

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0; // set to zero for no timeout
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$file_contents = curl_exec($ch); // take out the spaces of curl statement!!
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($file_contents);  

?>
```

if i put the address in the browser i get the content without any issue, but if i try to get it on PHP or other code i have issues, what can i do? i try use file_get_contents(); too but i don't get anything, only issues and issues

Comment: Define the term _issues_

Comment: yes i'm getting: 403 - Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that they are checking user agents and blocking PHP. Set this before using file_get_contents:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1');
```

If they are checking user agents, they may be doing so to prevent people from doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read a little bit about cURL on php.net?

here is how it works:

From [php.net:](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

```
$url = 'http://www.taringa.net/api/efc6d445985d5c38c5515dfba8b74e74/json/Users-GetUserData/apptastico';  

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); // set to true to see the header 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE); // show the body 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$content = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo $content
```

Comment: yes i already read about that, but i still getting a "403 - Forbidden" error

Comment: for debugging try using file_get_contents($url); echo it

Comment: you should look at the documentation of the api, they must be blocking some calls